# AWS Route 53: how to map single Route53 domain to multiple CloudFront domain names

Tags: dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

So I have 3 static web applications that are served from their respective S3 buckets. I have also used 3 CloudFront Distribution for each website. I have purchased a domain from route53 and want to use that domain against this 3 CloudFront distribution.

The question is would that be possible to have a single domain to map multiple CloudFront distributions? In other words, can route53 do the path routing to different CloudFront sites based on the route in the URL path? if so how can I achieve that? or if someone could point me to the correct document would be great.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Path routing can be achieved in CloudFront, not in r53. Just use 1 CF distro with 3 origins.

Comment: That worked. Thanks :) @jellycsc